# saving figure in png does not work properly

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a figure like below:
[image]

which I set the figure window to full screen with below command

```
figure('units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1])
```

but when I am trying to automatically save the figure with 
`print(sprintf('%s-%s-grind-compare.png', envs_{e}, methods_{m}), '-r300', '-dpng')` The result would be as below:
[image]

**Question:** How can I fix this?

Comment: Try saving the figure using [saveas](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/saveas.html) command.

Comment: This probably isn't the perfect answer for you, but this [export_fig](https://github.com/altmany/export_fig) basically attempts to resolve issues of "print not printing like it looks on the screen".

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the best way, but you could save with a much higher resolution then resize the file - I believe the r300 is setting the resolution and then the font size is relative to that figure size.